# How do I display the content type name (not a machine name) and their quantity that is on the website on the page?

Tags: nodes, 9

I have 2 content types(nodes) on the website: *Blog* and *FAQ*. I need to display the name of the content type and how many nodes of those content types are present on the site, on two different lines.

> Blog Results 35
> FAQ Results 2

To implement this, I wrote this code.

```php
$search_result = $search_query->execute();

$rows = [];
foreach ($search_result->getResultItems() as $item) {
  $rows[$node->bundle()]['count'] += 1;
}

$build = [];

foreach ($rows as $key => $row) {
  $build[] = ['#markup' => $row['count']];
}

return $build;
```

It shows 352 on the page.

I heard that knowing the machine name of the node, I can get the name of the content type. The machine name for *Blog* is *blog*; the machine name for *FAQ* is *static_pages*.

What do I need to change or add to the second `foreach` to display the name of these content types and how many nodes of those content type are present in the site, on two different lines?

After the first `foreach` I get:

```php
$rows = ['blog' => ['count' => 35], 'static_pages' => ['count' => 2]];
```

`$node->labels()` and `$node->getTitle()` are not suitable because they display the node titles.

Comment: Views can do this.

Comment: @Kevin No, it must be implemented programmatically. There I just need to add a few lines of the code in the `foreach`. This is a requirement.

Comment: How are you building `$search_query`?

Comment: View displays can be called and executed programmatically.

Comment: If you literally just need the bundle label, replace `$node->bundle()` with `$node->type->entity->label()`